# Embedding Video via HTML5

Tags: html, video.js

I'm attempting to embed video via HTML5 and leveraging video.js http://www.videojs.com/

Seems to be working fine on Mac Chrome. Video start immediately. However, on Mac Safari - not so much. Video opens paused at the first frame and just sits till (apparently) the entire thing is loaded.

Makes sense that the video has to load. But what is going on with Chrome that mitigates that, and why is the lag so apparent with Safari?

And what can I do to prevent the delay (e.g., I would like the video to start immediately when the page is loaded).

```
<div>
  <video width="640" height="360" preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" >
    <source src="href="/sites/default/files/videos/original/1918_Pandemic_Flu.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    No flash player has been set up. <a href="/admin/config/media/video/players">Please select a player to play Flash videos.</a></video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add  `controls autoplay` The autoplay attribute is a boolean attribute.

When present, the video will automatically start playing as soon as it can do so without stopping.since  some times MIME types not support in browser 
or `<video loop autoplay width='100%' height='100%' src='//video.mp4' type='video/mp4'></video>`
or
 `<video loop autoplay controls="true" width='100%' height='100%' src='//video.mp4' type='video/mp4'></video>`